# Are devas infallible when talking to humans?

Tags: gods, philosophy, darshan, truth

Whenever devas communicate with humans, is it possible for them to communicate lies or errors? Or is this an impossibility?

I'm not talking about the human misinterpreting the message, which is always possible, but about if the error can be in the deva's message itself.

Comment: why not? devas are jivas also.

Comment: @SwamiVishwananda So they can make errors and lie when talking to humans?